# how to find time gaps and gap length between mysql table records?

Tags: mysql, gaps-in-data

My table looks like this:

| id | time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-17 17:44:26 |
| 2 | 2021-07-17 17:44:26 |
| 3 | 2021-07-17 17:44:26 |
| 4 | 2021-07-17 17:44:31 |
| 5 | 2021-07-17 17:44:31 |
| 6 | 2021-07-17 17:44:31 |
| 7 | 2021-07-17 17:44:36 |
| 8 | 2021-07-17 17:44:36 |
| 9 | 2021-07-17 17:44:36 |
| 10 | 2021-07-17 17:44:41 |
| 11 | 2021-07-17 17:44:41 |
| 12 | 2021-07-17 17:44:41 |
| 13 | 2021-07-17 17:44:51 |
| 14 | 2021-07-17 17:44:51 |
| 15 | 2021-07-17 17:44:51 |
| 16 | 2021-07-17 17:44:56 |
| 17 | 2021-07-17 17:44:56 |
| 18 | 2021-07-17 17:44:56 |
| 19 | 2021-07-17 17:45:02 |
| 20 | 2021-07-17 17:45:02 |
| 21 | 2021-07-17 17:45:02 |

I have MySQL 8.0.21

always next 3 rows have same time and then beetwen usualy is 5 seconds time gap, how to find all gap longer than 8 second and also count gap time to get something like that:

| gap_id | gap_time_start | gap_length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-17 17:44:41 | 10 |

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: @FaNo_FN MySQL 8.0.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 8+ you can use the `LEAD()` window function like this:

```
select * from (
    SELECT id as gap_id, 
        `time` as gap_start_time, 
        timediff( lead(`time`) over W, `time`) as gap_length 
        from `myTable` window w as (order by `time` asc)
    ) T where T.gap_length > 5;
```

Output:

```
12, 2021-07-17 17:44:41, 00:00:10
18, 2021-07-17 17:44:56, 00:00:06
```

Reference: [LEAD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead)